# Is there a way New->Scala Class in intellij can default to creating a case class (vs a regular class)?

Tags: scala, intellij-scala

When I right-click and follow New->Scala Class, Intellij defaults to creating a new regular class.  I'd like it to default to creating a case class.

A small thing... but annoying when creating a lot of new classes.

Is it configurable somewhere?

Answer (score 9):

1. Open `File>Settings` and go to `Files and Code Templates`.
2. Click on <kbd>+</kbd> and add name **Scala Case Class**, set *extension* to **scala** and provide correct template. You might copy template from **Scala Class** and modify it accordingly.
   [image]
3. Click on `New > Scala Class`. Dialog should have now option **Scala Case Class**.

Comment: This worked!  Is there a way to make it the default in the dialog's options?  Thinking it might be alphabetical I gave it a name like "A Scala Case Class" but it still put it at the end.

Comment: I can't find a way to move it higher either :/